# Where to get older cookie vmod (libvmod_cookie.so)?

Tags: varnish

I'm looking for the older cookie vmod (libvmod_cookie.so) to use with varnish-cache v.5.0.  I know that's pretty old but I'm locked in for now. Everything now points to git, which doesn't have it because it's been part of varnish since 6.4.  Where to find it?

Answer (score 2):

The source code for `vmod_cookie` can be found on https://github.com/varnish/varnish-modules.

Unfortunately Varnish Cache 5.x is end-of-life, but if you really want to dig up a version, you can browse through the commits.

While `vmod_cookie` has been an in-tree VMOD for Varnish Cache for a number of releases now, https://github.com/varnish/varnish-modules/tree/6.0/src still has it. Maybe check https://github.com/varnish/varnish-modules/blame/6.0/src/vmod_cookie.c and see how much it differs.

It may be a bit of work, but you might be able to compile that code, or at least a historic version of that code on 5.x.

No guarantees though, because remember: 5.x is end-of-life.

> My advice: run Varnish Cache 6.0 LTS. See https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/downloads/#linux-packages

Comment: I'd be better served if I get project approval for upgrading my version of varnish - that's going to need to happen eventually.  We've been dragging our feet because of limited resources, but instead of hacking out a solution that's not supported, better to start fresh I think.  Thanks for the input though.  I assumed the .c file I saw where you pointed in that project wasn't quite the same and likely to give me headaches. ;-)

Comment: Hi @Kari, I'll check internally to see if we can dig up a commit that is compatible with v5.0. But it comes with the typical disclaimer that v5.0 is end-of-life with some security vulnerabilities. Keep you posted.

Comment: After checking with our developers, there is no real solution for Varnish Cache 5.x. We apparently deliberately removed the old releases from GitHub to discourage users to try this on 5.x or older. As mentioned, there are known security vulnerabilities on these old releases. The only real solution is upgrading to 6.0 LTS or non-LTS version.